# Paint ceiling or skimming required

Tags: ceiling, repainting

I recently removed the texture from my ceiling and managed to reach the plaster board.  Will I be able to prime and then paint the ceiling or if it needs to be skimmed by a professional?
[image: eceiling]

Comment: It looks like there is quite a bit of sanding to be done before painting can begin, but the surface itself seems pretty good.

Comment: a smooth finish is one of the toughest because any imperfections show up. A pole sander and some topping mud with a wide knife (12-14") take a little bit of time but you can do this and make it look as good as a professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I have had to do a lot of these ceiling strip and refinish jobs. they are not fun and take some time.  You will need to at least remud most, if not all the seams and screws.  The first step is to sand the existing joints and fastener spots.  Don't get crazy, but knock down all raised areas.  Then use joint compound and treat the seams, etc exactly as you would for new sheetrock.  Also skim any areas where the drywall was damaged during the stripping.  Use an eight to ten inch knife or trowel. A bow trowel is best, but not easy for an amature. All the same rules as new drywall finishing apply.  If you are not comfortable doing this, get someone to do it for you.  Don't waste your time and money priming and painting as I know you will be very disappointed in the results without doing the finishing first. Painting over bad joints etc, will only amplify the imperfections and make it more difficult to fix.  You spent so much time and effort removing the popcorn, it would be a shame not to finish the project properly.

Answer (score 0):

Wow!  That is a great job of removing texture.

You have (at least) three choices:

- Add texture—maybe one you like more than the old one—which greatly helps hide joints, fasteners, and other imperfections.
- Skim coat and sand.  Making it perfectly flat may take a newbie quite a bit of effort.  Expect at least four coats.  Use non-diffuse work lights well away from center:  the best would be next to the ceiling at the far edge from where you are working to readily reveal shadows of non-flat features.
- Paint and hope for the best.  If it is ugly, maybe you could keep the curtains closed and engineer the light so the ceiling isn't noticeable.